# Как поменять кодировку в блокноте?

Tags: windows-10

Как поменять кодировку в блокноте на 866 (OEM-русская)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Блокнот Windows этого не умеет делать.](https://safezone.cc/threads/kak-soxranit-fajl-v-kodirovke-cp866-oem.23958/) Попробуйте воспользоваться сторонними редакторами, например [AkelPad](https://safezone.cc/threads/russkij-tekst-v-konsoli.22573/) или [Notepad++](https://safezone.cc/threads/notepad.23102/).